# How to access the app from app floder

Tags: macos

Iam very new to Mac OS, also i have build the application for Mac on windows XP OS and it created floders in target folder such as build , classes,plugins, plugins-dev and xxx_app.
I read some post that in Mac we can access app from .app floder. Folder structure goes like this  xxx_app-->xxx.app-->contents-->MacOS and xxx_app-->xxx.app-->contents-->Reources.
So which file have to invoke to open app in MacOS and where it will be located.

**Edit**

Do i have to zip complete target folder and provide to client or only app folder or only app floder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That folder structure, that ends with `.app` is a Mac OS X [application bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle).

When you say "access the app" - I'm assuming you mean "run this program". From the command prompt on a Mac OS system, you can run the application by giving the path to its application bundle. For example:

```
$ open /Applications/iTunes.app
```

will launch iTunes.

As to giving the binary to your client: again, the application bundle folder should be sufficient; assuming your program has no other dependencies that are in the target directory.